# new WP_Query based on average values of meta fields

Tags: wp-query

I have 5 different meta (numerical) fields for a custom post type and I need to create a query based on the average values from those fields (kinda like a rating system, post with highest average rating from those 5 different rating field should come first).

The meta boxes are setup and working smoothly, however I am stuck when I have to query the posts by the average values..

I have absolutely no idea how to get those values before the query, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not save the average as another meta field & then query that instead?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, that's exactly I did after getting no replies here.

Comment: It's definitely the best way to go, regardless :)